# How to search Wiktionary for a word in another language using its English definition?

Tags: wiktionary

If I want to find the Swahili word for "tiger", I would usually search Google for `swahili tiger site:wiktionary.org`. Or I might go into Wiktionary's search input and type "tiger swahili", but that's not usually very good results, if any. Google is usually my best bet, but sometimes it doesn't find things. And it takes a long time to do this one-by-one.

Is there a built-in way somehow to search for the *English* definition of some foreign language word, so I can find the foreign language word? So I might want to find the Hebrew word for "Camel", how can I search "hebrew camel" efficiently/effectively to find the Hebrew word for it in Wiktionary?

Answer (score 1):

There's a column with different languages you may switch to on the left side of the word definition page (vewing the page in a full mode on a PC).

Or you could replace the language in the wiktionary link.
For example: you're on English wiktionary: en.wiktionary.org/wiki/tiger, you could replace the 'en' part in the link with the language you need (given that the correspondent page exists in another language), like this: ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/tiger for Russian. Or 'fr' for French, etc...

Answer (score 1):

### Why use Wiktionary for Translation?

This seems like a direct translation task.  Why not use Google Translate for it?  Seems like the approaches you are using are a circular way to get to a translation.

You can navigate to https://translate.google.com/ and choose whatever to/from languages you want.  It can do language auto-detection if you don't name the language, and will additionally provide limited definitions, context etc.

A searches URL with autodetection of the from language follow the following format:
`<URL>?tl=<toLanguage>&text=<textToTranslate>`

- **Swahili:**
  `https://translate.google.com/?tl=sw&text=tiger`
- **Italian:**
  `https://translate.google.com/?tl=it&text=tiger`
- **French:**
  `https://translate.google.com/?tl=fr&text=tiger`

### Google Search does this too

Keep in mind that Google Translate is very well integrated into Google's search, so a simple Google search for `'translate tiger swahili'` will return largely an identical result to doing it in Google Translate.  You can see that in the images below.

### Google Search for Translations using the letter <kbd>T</kbd>

If you do translations a lot and are okay using a Google search that leverages Google Translate, you can make things quicker by using Chrome to create a custom search and access it using a shortcut letter on your address bar.

###### INSTRUCTIONS

1. In Chrome's **address bar** type `chrome://settings/searchEngines` then press <kbd>ENTER</kbd>
2. In the **Site search** section click <kbd>Add</kbd>
3. Then in the **Add search Engine** dialog put the following:
      **Engine:**     `Google (Translations)`
      **Shortcut:**  `T`
      **URL:**        
   `https://www.google.com/search?q=translate+%s`
4. Then click <kbd>Add</kbd>

Now, whenever you want to search for a translation using Google you will simply type
 
 **`t tiger swahili`**
   [image]

---

## Images

The following images compare the results of the three approaches discussed:

1. Google Translate
2. Google Search
3. Google <kbd>T</kbd> Search

##### 1 Google Translate Result

`https://translate.google.com/?tl=sw&text=tiger`   [[ Try Link ]](https://translate.google.com/?tl=sw&text=tiger)
[image]

##### 2 Google Search Result

`https://www.google.com/search?q=translate+tiger+swahili`   [[ Try Link ]](https://www.google.com/search?q=translate+tiger+swahili)
[image]

##### 3 Google <kbd>T</kbd> Search Result

`t tiger swahili`  
Identical to the Google Search result (#2 above) because `t` is simply being replaced with `https://www.google.com/search?q=translate+` by Chrome
[image]

Answer (score 0):

For example, if you want to find out how to say *tiger* in Swahili and have an English description for it, you have to search on the English version of Wiktionary, which has the **en.wiktionary.org** sub-domain.

1. Search via Google.
   1.1. You type the string `tiger site:en.wiktionary.org`
   1.2. If it exists and Google has offered it, you select the tiger page
   1.3. Then you need to find the **English language** section and click on **Translations** within the English section
2. Search on en.wiktionary.org
   2.1. In the search field in the middle of the blue box, type *tiger* and press enter
   2.2. If the page exists then it will take you to it, otherwise it will offer a list of similar pages (maybe you have a typo)
   1.3. Then you need to find the **English language section** and click on **Translations** in the English section

There are currently around 7 million words in the English Wiktionary, but they are words in all languages, so it's not necessarily English or Swahili. Therefore, if you can't find something, it probably doesn't exist (word, English section, or proper translation). However, there is one more option to use wiki projects and get a translation of a word. And that is cross-language links of articles from Wikipedia on Wikidata.

The procedure would be as follows:

3. Searching wikidata.org
   3.1. Type *tiger* into the search field at the top right and press enter
   3.2. You will get a list of similar-sounding items, where according to the label (in this case "species of big cat") you select the correct one
   3.3. In the **Wikipedia** section, which is usually halfway down or on the right, you search by language codes. Language codes can be found, for example, on Wikipedia in the box on the right. For example, Swahili has the code *swa*, but it is not in the list, so unfortunately the translation of the word is not here, however, for example, Hebrew, which has the code *he* is here: *тигрис*

It's not an ideal way, but it can provide translations of some specific terms into non-main languages. If you want to make sure that the term on Wikidata is correct, you click on it and you get to, for example, the Hebrew Wikipedia, where I might not understand anything, but I would be able to tell from the pictures if it is the translation of tiger as an animal to Hebrew.